# Is this a bet or a dare?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, pronunciation-vs-spelling

If i tell a friend to climb a car an he get’s 2 euro if he does this. Is this than a bet or a dare?

Comment: Just  never  tell a friend to do this!,

Comment: Depends on how you phrase it.  “I dare you to do it” or “I bet you won’t do it”  it’s the difference between paying them for what they did versus paying them because you were wrong.

Comment: And if you just tell them to do it and you'll pay them 2 euros, then it's neither a bet or a dare, it's simply (trivial) employment.

Comment: `An he get's` ? Really?

Comment: For me a bet involves some sort of stake on both sides. For instance "I'll bet you €2 you can't climb that tree" implies that, if the other person can climb it you will give him €2 but if he can't climb it he will pay you €2. The other person does, if course, gave to accept the bet. If the other person is challenged to do something but loses nothing apart from reputation or status if he does not do it, it is a dare. Even if there is a reward for completing the challenge it is still a dare if the challenged person does not risk anything tangible.

Comment: It's an incitement. In most jurisdictions, it's a criminal offence. // The twinning of 'tell' (a jussive, command) and the promise of remittance is problematic, implying a stick as well as a carrot. This probably makes the question infelicitous: along the lines of << (3 + 4) = 7, but is (3 Ϡ 4) five or twelve? >> ie the alternative answers look fine, but the question is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @KillingTime that this is neither a bet nor a dare as the initial verb in the structure is a command - "tell", with the function of "tell someone to do something".